# force directed layout, list down the source and target value on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

With the Mobile Patent Suit example by Mike Bostock as an example, I want to list down the type value in a DIV class text on mouse over of the circles. I tried to get it work. I don't know why all the values are listed in DIV class text.My working code can be seen here.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqthF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this part:

```
var div = d3.select("body").selectAll(".usertext")
    .data(links)
.enter().append("div")
.attr("class", "usertext")
.text(function(d) { return d.type;});
```

And put this code instead:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("source");
var li = ul.firstChild;
li.innerText = links[a.index].type;
ul.appendChild(li)
```

Html from your example should be like this:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<div class="usertext">
<ul id="source">
<li>Source</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here full code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zkAtD

Comment: but i want to list the type value in my div class text like <div class="usertext">
<ul>
<li>Licensing</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: @ Stanislav Terleckiy, refere this visualization [link] http://languagenetwork.cotrino.com/ I need exactly like this. When i mouseover the circles, corresponding type value should appear in left panel

Comment: @ Stanislav Terleckiy, again its not working. can you post in codepen / jsfiddle

Comment: Perfect. Working like a charm

Comment: @ Stanislav Terleckiy, links[a.index].type shows wrong data. can you please check?